# Detecting database change in Ruby

Tags: ruby, database, events, sinatra

I have an API that automatically posts to a callback I set up which ends up saving the data to the database I created.

Is there a way to detect when new data is saved and, as a result, causes an action like displaying the new data in the view as a refresh?

I'm messing around with the Instagram real time.

Comment: Unfortunately the subject is pretty broad these days, and will continue to grow, and asking us to describe how to do it is off-topic because it'd take a book to describe everything. You need to do the detective work, research and try things then ask specific questions about your implementation. Read https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology as a starting place.

Comment: That is fair.  I will look deeper.  Thanks for taking the time to comment.